# How to use an AWS instance to connect to a server on my local computer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking

I have an HTTP server running on my local computer, and I would like to be able to connect to it remotely. I would like to connect to a port on the aws instance and have it forwarded to my local computer. This is because my local computer can't be connected to directly. I would like to create a connection from my computer to the instance, and forward an incoming connection to my computer over that connection. 
Edit: I am able to curl the website from the AWS instance, so the port forwarding works, but I can't connect to that port from outside.

Comment: What's the issue with connecting to your home computer?  If it's a changing, dynamic IP address you may want to consider something along the lines of Dynamic DNS to keep a static address pointed to a dynamic IP.

Comment: @Nathan Champion Sorry if my question is vague, but I want to connect to my home computer through a connection that I make with my home computer to the AWS instance, since my home computer is not static, but my AWS instance is.

Comment: Please edit your question to include details of how you have configured the connection between your home computer and the EC2 instance. Also FYI, StackOverflow is a site for Programming questions, so your question might get closed.